# Why use .getData() instead of .data

Tags: java

This is just a form question.

Using Java, why when trying to return a value from an object do you use `object.getData()` from a defined `getData()` function within the class instead of simply using `object.data`.

They both seem to return the same thing except that object.getData() is more typing and requires you to define a function in the object unnecessarily.

Comment: `public Foo getFoo() { return MethodToCreateDeepCopyOfFoo(); }` for example will allow you to return data while preventing the caller from altering the state of the original object. It's all about information hiding and information control.

Comment: one enables the owner of the **attribute** to determine how its data is **accessed/modified** whereas the other completely ignores the concept of **encapsulation**.